# UITableView with Full Screen cells - pagination breaks after fetch more rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, pagination

My app uses a UITableView to implement a TikTok-style UX. Each cell is the height of the entire screen. Pagination is enabled, and this works fine for the first batch of 10 records I load. Each UITableViewCell is one "page". The user can "flip" through the pages by swiping, and initially each "page" fully flips as expected. However when I add additional rows by checking to see if the currently visible cell is the last one and then loading 10 more rows, the pagination goes haywire. Swiping results in a partially "flipped" cell -- parts of two cells are visible at the same time. I've tried various things but I'm not even sure what the problem is. The tableView seems to lose track of geometry.

Note: After the pagination goes haywire I can flip all the way back to the first cell. At that point the UITableView seems to regain composure and once again I'm able to flip correctly through all of the loaded rows, including the new ones.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Pause the video if the cell is ended displaying
    if let cell = cell as? HomeTableViewCell {
        cell.pause()
    }
    if let indices = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
        for index in indices {
            if index.row >= self.data.count - 1 {
                self.viewModel!.getPosts()
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can try tableView.scrollToItem method to fix the cell position.

Comment: I faced same issue, so I ditched UITableView and used https://gist.github.com/chanonly123/fd58b04b73e930fd0feef97d3aa732fe

Comment: @ChanOnly123 - thanks, I tried a few different ways of using scrollToItem but so far haven't found any approach that solves the problem. Thanks very much for that alternative code -- if this turns out to be a fundamental limitation of UITableVIew I'll try your code next. Cheers!

Comment: @ChanOnly123 - I put a question in your github -- could you take a look if you have a moment? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and as I couldn't find a solution anywhere else here's how I solved it without using Texture:

I used the `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol to fetch the new data to be inserted

```
extension TikTokTableView: UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    viewModel.prefetchRows(at: indexPaths)
}
```

}

`prefetchRows` will execute the request if the visible cell is the last one, as in my case

```
func prefetchRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    if indexPaths.contains(where: isLastCell) {
        getPosts(type: typeOfPosts, offset: posts.count, lastPostId: lastPost)
    }
}

private func isLastCell(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.row == posts.count - 1
}
```

I have a `weak var view` delegate type `TikTokTableViewDelegate` in my view model to have access to a function `insertItems` implemented by my `TikTokTableView`. This function is used to inform the `UITableView` where to insert the incoming posts at

```
self.posts.append(contentsOf: response.posts)
let indexPathsToReload = self.calculateIndexPathToReload(from: response.posts)
self.view?.insertItems(at: indexPathsToReload)


private func calculateIndexPathToReload(from newPosts: [Post]) -> [IndexPath] {
    let startIndex = posts.count - newPosts.count
    let endIndex = startIndex + newPosts.count
    print(startIndex, endIndex)
    return (startIndex..<endIndex).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
}
```

and this is the `insertItems` function implemented in `TikTokTableView` and here is the key: **If we try to insert those rows, the pagination of the table will fail and leave that weird offset, we have to store the indexPaths in a local property and insert them once the scroll animation has finished**.

```
extension TikTokTableView: TikTokTableViewDelegate {
func insertItems(at indexPathsToReload: [IndexPath]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // if we try to insert rows in the table, the scroll animation will be stopped and the cell will have a weird offset
            // that's why we keep the indexPaths and insert them on scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(:)
            self.indexPathsToReload = indexPathsToReload
        }
    }
}
```

Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, we have access to `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, this func is triggered at the end of a user's scroll and this is the time when we insert the new rows

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !indexPathsToReload.isEmpty {
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToReload, with: .none)
        indexPathsToReload = []
    }
}
```